# Apache CXF interceptor configuration

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, cxf, jax-rs

I created a SOAP interceptor as described in [CXF docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html):

```
public class SoapMessageInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    public SoapMessageInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.USER_PROTOCOL);
    }
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage soapMessage) throws Fault {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and registered it with the bus in Spring's application context:

```
  <cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
      <ref bean="soapMessageInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
  </cxf:bus>

  <jaxws:endpoint id="customerWebServiceSoap"
        implementor="#customerWebServiceSoapEndpoint"
        address="/customerService"/>
```

All was working fine until I added a REST service:

```
  <jaxrs:server id="customerWebServiceRest" address="/rest">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
      <ref bean="customerWebServiceRestEndpoint" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
  </jaxrs:server>
```

The problems is that the SOAP interceptor is now being triggered on REST requests also, which results in a class cast exception when the REST service is invoked.

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">
  <ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.message.XMLMessage
    cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage
  </ns1:faultstring>
</ns1:XMLFault>
```

Is there any way to restrict the interceptor to SOAP messages only through configuration?

**Update**

Looks like I missed the page in the docs that describes this.
Scroll down to [Difference between JAXRS filters and CXF interceptors](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can attach interceptors to an individual endpoint rather than to the bus:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="customerWebServiceSoap"
    implementor="#customerWebServiceSoapEndpoint"
    address="/customerService">
  <jaxws:inInterceptors>
    <ref bean="soapMessageInterceptor"/>
  </jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: But what if I want to share interceptor configurations between endpoints? Adding them to cxf:bus or jaxws:server does not result in the same behavior as adding them to the endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to configure your interceptor like this:

```
  <cxf:bus name="someBus">
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
      <ref bean="soapMessageInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
  </cxf:bus>
```

By defining the `name` of the bus, which according to documentation, identifies a bus as a unique `Spring` bean. Then in your `JAX-WS` endpoint configuration you need to specify the bus referencing to that name:

```
  <jaxws:endpoint id="customerWebServiceSoap"
        implementor="#customerWebServiceSoapEndpoint"
        address="/customerService"
        bus="someBus"/>
```

And this `bus` should work only on this `JAX-WS` endpoint.